# Why should the split property hold in AQFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime, locality

In algebraic quantum field theory, one assigns complex unital $*$-algebras (or von Neumann algebras) $\mathfrak{A}(O)$ to open regions $O$ of Minkowski spacetime. I am reading an [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06936) by Chris Fewster, in which he states that the [split property](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+inclusion+of+von+Neumann+algebras) is important in AQFT to address the following concern:

> "It turns out to be important to ensure that the regions in question do not touch at
> their boundaries"

My question is, why is it important to ensure the regions don't touch along the boundaries?

Comment: If they touch generally speaking the split property fails. This implies that the algebra of observables generated by the two regions (causally separated) is not the tensor product while the systems are independent. This fact shows that the idea that independent systems are automatically described by tensor products is not necessarily true and it cannot be assumed as a fundamental requirement.

Comment: @ValterMoretti thanks! So if I have this right, the split property is relied on as the justification for using the decomposition of a global Hilbert space into a tensor product of local Hilbert spaces? (in particular when these spaces are infinite dimensional)

Comment: It depends on the type of Von Neumann algebras. The disaster arises with type III algebras (necessarily in infinite dim spaces you are right), the standard in QFT. In finite dimensional spaces everything goes automatically right instead.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Ok let's say I have type III$_1$ von Neumann algebras (like I *should* in AQFT), what is this disaster you speak of, are you just referring to the failure of the split property or something else?

Comment: I mean the fact that independent systems are generally not represented by a tensor product.

Comment: ok thanks, yeah just wanted to clarify.

Comment: I think everything is discussed in Chris’ paper, he is extremely clear usually...

Comment: @ValterMoretti yes you are right I gave Chris' paper some more time... it seems that the motivation is something like *thermodynamic assumptions* $\implies$ *nuclearity constraints* $\implies$ *the split property*. Thanks!